# Sending Data from android app to web application

Tags: android, android-intent, web-applications

I newbie in android.

The requirement is i need to invoke android app from web app and then i need to send a string from android app to web app.

This is what i have done so for.

**1) create link from web app to mobile app (it works)**

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.appname.demo;end">click to load</a>
```

**2) Mobile app has one text box and a button and i needs to send value of textbox to web app when the button click.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.example.helloapp");
    Log.e("IntentTest", i.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
                value = mEdit.getText().toString();
        // I need to send value to web application

            }
      });
}
```

**How do i send EditText value to web application.**

Comment: what is the 'web application' here ? is it your own app ?

Comment: @harvey_slash Grails application which developed by me

Comment: and by 'sending', you want to start your app and be able to access the string, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is probably perform a HTTP POST. This is very simple in Java, just use the HttpURLConnection class.

for example you could do something like this.

```
URL url = new URL("www.yoursite.com");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   

//Send request
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
wr.flush ();
wr.close ();

try {
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
 readStream(in); // Your function that reads the result from the server
finally {
 urlConnection.disconnect();
  }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a string using intents

this is how you can send:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
emailIntent.putExtra("VALUE", valueofthestringyouwanttosend);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and to receive(run from your web app)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value= intent.getStringExtra("VALUE");
```

Comment: how can i use Intent in java or grails web application ?